# Entity Framework Core - Use generated query

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a structure of 26 tables which I want to load data from the database and get them inside the code. For example I use the `Include` method to join the related data of an entity:

```
var Application = dbContext.Applications
                           .Include(a => a.PwEmployee)
                           .Include(a => a.Promoters).ThenInclude(f => f.Addresses)
                           .Include(a => a.Promoters).ThenInclude(f => f.People)
                           ... and many more
```

I don't want to include the generated query since it is not that readable and also not the problem here. What I want to do is use the generated query in a stored procedure and do this:

```
List<Application> Applications = await dbContext.Applications.FromSqlRaw("Exec GetFullApplication {0}", uuid).ToListAsync();
```

When I do this with the generated SQL query from EF Core, I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: ID

When it works from EF Core to the database, shouldn't it work also the other way around with said SQL statement that EF Core generated? Is there any performance improvement to expect when doing this?

Comment: See [Raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), [Raw SQL queries - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations), [Composing with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq) and [Raw SQL queries - Including related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data) sections of the EF Core docs.

Comment: It should not work. Eager Loading queries has no direct translation in SQL. Use `AsSplitQuery()` if you have performance issues and stay with LINQ.

Comment: The problem is that your generated SQL is likely returning rows for the same table multiple times since it thinks it's more efficient to do things in a single query than multiple. When EF runs that, internally it knows about the dupes and can handle it. I'm always suspicious of queries with so many includes anyway. There's almost never a good use case for returning all that data in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The solution was not to use Stored Procedures but to use Views since they are treated like tables. Something like this works:

`IQueryable<Application> Applications = dbContext.Applications.FromSqlRaw($"Select * from ApplicationsMinimal where ApplicationUUID = '{uuid}'");`

And then calling the includes on that list

Comment: @DavidG I get your point. I have an optional parameter that comes from my api and decides if all the related data gets loaded or just the necessary ones. I do this only if you want it.